# facebook "the open graph object has the wrong type for the given property" for video.watches

Tags: android, facebook, action

I see that most of my user/video.watches requests (if not all) get the above error (through the Facebook console).
Here's my code:

```
    Request request = null;
    final Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("tv_show", show.facebookPageId); //<String: a facebook page id..>
    params.putString("fb:explicitly_shared", "true");
    request = new Request(session, "me/video.watches", params, HttpMethod.POST, m_callback);
    executeRequest(request);
```

The session HAS the following permissions (I verify before calling the code above):

```
private static final List<String>   PERMISSIONS                     = Arrays.asList("publish_actions",
                                                                            "status_update");                                   // ,
```

Comment: Are you sure the pages you're linking are actually tv shows (i.e. they have the og:type = tv_show in the meta tags)?

Comment: Yup. Doesn't happen all the time, it's inconsistent. Usually works fine, sometimes fails. When it fails, there is no error on the client side - I just see that on the developer console/insights/developer/errors I get API errors..